# App Engine: Redirect to latest version

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I would like to redirect my test users to the latest version of my app engine application. I heard you could access the newest version with the url `latest-dot-project-id.appspot.com`, but this just serves the default version.

Any ideas how to redirect to the newest version, which could have the url `version-dot-project-id.appspot.com`?

I know I could access the API to get the newest version, but I'm also having trouble getting the data from there with a service account.

Comment: why don't you set the newest version as the default?

Comment: As said in the post, it's for the test users. Normal users should see the default version.

Comment: The distinction you're making between "normal" and "test" is both significant and, alas, ambigous. By "test" to you mean "testers" (in the QA sense), or do you mean a subset of your normal community that you want to expose a new version to?

Comment: Test users are internal testers in QA sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the Google App Engine Admin API to get the newest version.

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1beta4/apps/-----/modules/default/versions");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.json_decode($client->getAccessToken())->access_token;

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

            $versions = json_decode(curl_exec ($ch))->versions;
            curl_close ($ch);

            $newest_version = "0";
            foreach($versions as $version){
                if(str_replace("-", "", $version->id) > str_replace("-", "", $newest_version)){
                    $newest_version = $version->id;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You *should* be able to use the generic **latest** keyword (instead of figuring out which specific version of that module is latest) to reach any module you need:

`latest-dot-<modulename>-dot-<appname>.appspot.com`.

At least in python it works...

In the `latest-dot-project-id.appspot.com` construct you didn't specify the module name which is likely why you only hit the **default** module.

More details in the [Routing via URL doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/routing#routing_via_url)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, apps don't have programmatic access to available versions, so figuring this out what the "latest" version is is going to require that you give is a reserved name. How about `test`? Upload the version to be tested using `version: test`, and have your testers hit it. Then, when you want to go live with the tested version, upload it again with a "real" version, then make that the default. This second upload should go pretty quickly, assuming you didn't change anything.

FWIW, many people using an entirely separate application name for their testing version so that testers aren't modifying production data.

Comment: There is the App Engine API, which would be a PERFECT solution. But I cannot seem to find out how to get an access_token from a OAuth Service Account.

Comment: I can corroborate this - it's much easier to use a staging environment on a separate module, rather than version, and additionally changing the namespace (datastore, memcache, etc) by investigating the current module using `google.appengine.api.modules`

Comment: Oh, that said, from the python runtime you can definitely get the current versions with `get_versions` on the module api: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/functions

Comment: Sure, but you can't, as far as I know, get access to the _latest_ version, where latest means "a new version that I've uploaded for testers."

Answer (score 1):

If the test users aren't a predefined group that actively have to return feedback and what is needed/desired is a way to slowly rollout a feature over a period while monitoring logs etc, you can take advantage of [**App Engine's traffic splitting**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/#traffic-splitting) functionality. This can be found on the versions page of your app engine's project page in the [cloud developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

Traffic can be split based on cookies or ip addresses. Either of those come with little quirks that can be easily worked around though.

> You must choose whether to split the traffic by IP address or an HTTP cookie. It's easier to set up an IP address split, but a cookie split is more precise.

More about traffic splitting [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/developers-console/#traffic-splitting).

Comment: The issue is that the testers also should have access to the standard version.